# Artifacts and Color Distortions After Launching Games

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, desktop-computer

OS: Win 10 Home

CPU: i5-4670K @ 3.40GHz

GPU: EVGA GeForce GTX 780 Ti (OC: +150MHz)

RAM: 8 GB G-Skill Ares

PSU: Corsair HX850

Motherboard: ASUS Maximus VI Hero

Ambient room temp.: ~80F

Build is 3.5 years old with almost daily use.

When this issue first began, I had NBA 2K17 running. I had just installed it earlier in the day, and this was my first time playing it. I played it for just over an hour at the time. I was away from the computer (I can’t remember if the game was fullscreened or alt-tabbed at the time), and when I came back neither one of my two monitors would display an image. Apart from that, the computer seemed to be running normally. After force-restarting, I got to the desktop with no issues, but only one of my monitors was working initially. It didn’t take long for that monitor to also lose DVI input.

I once again forced a restart, but this time the issue occurred at mobo splash screen (after POST, before Windows). The monitor started briefly displayed some artifacting and color distortions before once again losing DVI input: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jucX.jpg This happened multiple times.

I checked a few connections and dusted inside the chassis. Boot, got to the desktop with no issues, both monitors working, all programs seemingly working fine. I was able to browse and watch videos just fine, but after launching Gwent, a card game, it ran for maybe a minute or two before I ran into my issue again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULq06.jpg This time, my monitors never lost DVI input, they just froze where they were. I couldn’t interact with them in any way. Upon forcing a restart, I was able to get back to the desktop once again and browse normally. I didn’t try to play anything, and thus, didn’t notice any problems until the next day.

The next day, I tried again with NBA 2K17. Once again, it only took about a minute or two, and I noticed that my GPU usage was maxed out and that it’s temperature at the time of the issue was just under 70 degrees C. Upon forcing a restart this time, the monitors once again stopped receiving DVI input in the loading screen just before the desktop as was the case the first night this issue appeared. However, there was no artifacting or discoloration, just a sudden lose of DVI input. This happened a few times in a row before I left the computer alone for a few minutes and gave the power supply a quick clean. The computer then booted up properly and got to the desktop.

The only other thing that was downloaded or installed just before the issue started (apart from NBA 2K17) was an update to Skype. When visual issues occur, there are no abnormal sounds from the chassis.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: What's causing the issue?

Comment: Well, your GPU has some kind of defect, so you should probably get in contact with whoever you bought it from.